# SVN - folder automerge

Tags: svn

Is there any way to merge only the differences between 2 folders automatically in SVN???

Let's say I am having this folder structure.

folder1

- src/main/java

  - com.app.func1

    - file1
    - file2
  - com.app.func1.some2

    - file3
    - file4

folder2

- src/main/java

  - com.app.func1

    - file1(slightly different from folder1's file1)
    - file2(same as folder1's file2)
  - com.app.func1.some2

    - file3(different from folder1's file3)
    - file4(same as folder1's file4)

If i give 2 folders, the folder1 and folder2 must be compared, and folder2's difference(if present) must be

automatically merged into folder1,and output must be automatically generated and look like,

folder1

- src/main/java

  - com.app.func1

    - file1
    - file2
  - com.app.func1.some2

    - file3
    - file4

Clearcase will do this.But i just want to know whether SVN will do something like this.If yes means how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Merge from folder1 to folder2, in the working copy of folder1, then commit.

This is the 2-URL merge explained in [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.merge).